# Telephony - Does Avaya have an API for retrieving the phone number of an incoming call?

Tags: telephony, avaya

I've been asked to develop an app in work and I am been looking for some solutions. Things will be easier if I could manage to retrieve the phone number of an incoming call so I can pass this to an RESTful web app.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is abit unspefic. What do you mean with Avaya?

In general the answer is Yes.

If you have the Communication Manager (the phone system, pbx) you need the Avaya Application Enablement Services (AES), this is an extra server. AES provides different interfaces you can use with various API's like JTAPI, TSAPI, DMCC.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer given already, for the Contact Centre suite, there is the CCT interfaces, which provides a plethora of API's, mostly in .NET and Web Services.